# Developer tools in windows edge browse localstorage

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm trying to use the new windows Edge browser for my web development.But just can't find any way to browse localstorage, cookies etc. inside the developer tools. How do I view them?

Best regards

Comment: (On a serious note: remember - develop in firefox (or chrome if you must, I'm against the unique browser ID sent to Google with every page request though) test in IE (IE was recently renamed to Edge))

Comment: yeah I know also using both FF and Chrome, but want to try out Edge....

Comment: Why? (this is also serious, do you have a good reason to actually want to /develop/ using IE/Edge)

Comment: Hi @RasmusChristensen, I tried answering your question below. let me know if it resolves your inquiry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are here: Debugger tab -> Folder icon on the left, under the "play" icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how did I not see that :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a really unexpected place to put it, really poor UX

Comment: I see the folder, but not Storage folder or whatever here. I'm on Edge 11.914.

Answer (score 9):

you can check localStorage object in the Console

1. Open F12 Developer Tools (press F12)
2. Go to Console tab
3. type localStorage in the input and click run/press enter. check the screenshot[image]

Comment: In 11.914, I see this option, but what do I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Storage is now in the **Application** tab.

[image]