# IE11, Edge doesn't support localStorage, sessionStorage for a file:-protocol

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, file-uri

I simply want to ask if this is well-known but I haven't found an answer in MS documentation:
values of the typeof( window.localStorage ), typeof( window.sessionStorage ) are both undefined. With http/https - protocols no problem.

Comment: Please share your code and rephrase your question so it will be more clear.

Comment: This link may help you. localstorage supports in Microsoft edge
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761513/developer-tools-in-windows-edge-browse-localstorage